# How do I cut a line in KDE Kate?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, kde, kate

What is the keyboard shortcut to copy the whole current line to the clipboard and then delete it?

This is functionally equivalent to:

<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

It's a common feature I use often in some text editors, such as:

- notepad++ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- nano <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (When used with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to paste.)

But it's not listed on [this cheatsheet](http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=veuviqxg4q2xtqi4&number=2) and I haven't managed to figure out how it's done in Kate.

Comment: The kate documentation is very useful https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/katepart/keybindings.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally stumbled across this today - I *knew* this basic functionality had to be somewhere already.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> when nothing is selected will *cut* the whole line after enabling the feature under the menu `Settings` > `Configure Kate...`

[image: screenshot of kate configure menu]

Answer (score 0):

I have Kate for Windows installed, and provided there is more than one line,

<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

does work.

If not then

<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

works instead

Comment: Thanks Paul, yes that's what I'm currently using. I'm sorry my question wasn't clear on that. I was hoping for something shorter, like just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Ah right, totally misunderstood.  I don't think Kate has this natively, and doesn't have a macro system built in, because it originates on KDE and the expectation is that the desktop environment would handle that.  Perhaps the best bet is to install AutoHotKey or similar and write your own shortcut?